How to disable Visual Studio Code tips on hovering attributes of elements
Whenever I hover props of an element, VS Code shows tips like a pop up. For example in this picture it shows the type of the stroke-linejoin:

I need to disable this behavior and replace it with a button press.
How can I remove the hover popup tips on elements properties and replace it with another shortcut key?

What language is this? HTML, XML? It'd help to add the tag for it.

Disabling Hover Tips on VScode
Go to Settings (Ctrl+,).
Search for hover.
Find Editor: Hover: Enabled and uncheck it.

Setting a Shortcut Key for Show Hover
Open Keyboard Shortcuts (Ctrl+K Ctrl+S).
Search for editor.action.showHover.
Click the pencil icon next to it and set a new shortcut key like Ctrl+Shift+I.

